# How can I mix an exe build application and interpreted .py file

Tags: python

I have a main application .exe file made from .py files.
Beside the main compiled application I have a .py file and I would like to handle objets declared in the main exe.
Can I ? How can I do this ?

Comment: unless your exe file is not reading any config information from that extra py file , you don't need anything else apart from exe file

Comment: Your `.py` file can't access Python objects defined in the `.exe`. The `.exe`does contain the bytecode for those objects but they are compressed inside the `.exe` and only get decompressed into a temporary folder when the `.exe` is run, and that folder gets deleted afterwards, and for obvious reasons it does not have a predictable name. Take a step back and [edit] your question to explain why you would want to do this. The only purpose of wrapping Python code in an `.exe` is to simplify deployment, for which you pay a price in startup time & disk space. Why not just `import` the `.py` file?